# Install SOAP extension to PHP 7.4

Tags: linux, soap, php-7.4

I try install SOAP extension to Linux Mint 19 Tara. I need version for PHP7.4, which is already working.

```
sudo apt install php7.4-soap
```

Result:

```
Loading package lists… Done
A dependency tree is created
Loading status information... Done
E: Unable to find package php7.4-soap
E: Unable to find package matching mask "php7.4-soap"
E: Unable to find package matching regular expression "php7.4-soap"
```

PHP7.4 have not SOAP extension or what I am doing wrong?

**EDIT:**

```
$ apt-cache search soap | grep "php"
libnusoap-php - SOAP toolkit for PHP
php-soap - SOAP module for PHP [default]
php7.2-soap - SOAP module for PHP
```

**mintupgrade check**
[image]

Comment: What does `apt-cache search soap | grep "php"` show you?

Comment: php-soap - SOAP module for PHP [default]
php7.2-soap - SOAP module for PHP

Answer (score 2):

Your OS is too old and not supported by Ondrej PPA anymore.

You can upgrade your OS to a more recent version (suggested as a long-term solution) or try to add this repository (not suggested, always be careful when adding external PPA repositories, especially for old OS):

```bash
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:jczaplicki/xenial-php74-temp
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt install php7.4-soap
```

Comment: References? As far as I know Mint 19 should be supported till 2023, and the Ubuntu version it's based on till 2028, so it's not *that* old.

Comment: @Krokomot Mint 19 is based on Ubuntu 18.04 that is not supported anymore (is ESM now, not LTS). Ondrej PPA removed support on June 15, 2023. References: https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2023/05/13/extended-security-maintenance-for-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-begins-31-may-2023/ and https://launchpad.net/%7Eondrej/+archive/ubuntu/php

Comment: I tried upgrade to 19.3 during https://linuxmint-user-guide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/upgrade-to-mint-20.html. Command apt install mintupgrade return me same result like before? Cannot find package mintupgrade. Unfortunately I cannot make clear installation.

Comment: So 19.3 is possible, but upgrade to 20 required downgrade PHP and phpmyadmin packages. A clean reinstallation would be better. How difficult it is to keep a tuned computer for development:(.

Comment: Not sure why you need to downgrade php if you're upgrading your OS. Have you tried to launch `apt-get update` and/or `apt-get upgrade`? Can you share the specific error you're receiving?

Comment: @AlbertoFecchi I added screenshot from mintupgrade check. At https://linuxmint-user-guide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/upgrade-to-mint-20.html is writtern "Some of your packages might have a lower version in Linux Mint 20 than in Linux Mint 19.3. To guarantee they function properly, they need to be downgraded."

Answer (score 0):

There might be several several cases in this problem. Either your installed php version is not 7.4 or there is already install soap extension with older version which is conflicting or you have php but there is no repo of php libraries in you ubuntu.

First case:

First check your installed php version by

```
php -v
```

Second Case:

Remove old version by

```
sudo apt remove php-soap
```

Then fix broken packages by

```
sudo apt --fix-broken install
```

Now install php7.4-soap by below commands

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
sudo apt update
sudo apt install php7.4
sudo apt install php7.4-soap
```

Comment: Unfortunatelly it does not work. How @AlbertoFecchi wrote, supporting of Tara (mint 19) is not in ppa:ondrej/php anymore. I upgrade mint from 19 to 19.3, but more is cannot be done without removing php from system.

Answer (score -1):

The package you are looking for is php7.2-soap, not php7.4-soap. In Linux Mint 19 Tara, the default version of PHP is 7.2.

You can install the PHP SOAP extension for PHP 7.2 by running the following command:

```
sudo apt install php7.2-soap
```

After installing the package, you may need to restart your web server for the changes to take effect.

Comment: Ok, but I need and use PHP7.4. Actually php7.2-soap is in the system, but it is not used by php7.4. Is not in phpinfo and using of soap function generate fatal error about non-existent class.